# Show the max date that is less than specific date but maximum among remaining group of data

Tags: sql, oracle

I have set of rows in the table with ID and Time, I am trying to get the row which has time less than a specific time mentioned, meanwhile the row selected should be maximum among the rest.

I have created a temporary table and added Id and corresponding date to it, now I am trying to compare the date in the table with the specific date, meanwhile selecting ID and Max Date in select but unfortunately, I am getting multiple rows, instead, I am looking for the row with max time after the specific time mentioned

```
create table temp_test (id varchar2(20),tmstmp date);
```

Random insert on below query with data

```
insert into temp_test values (10, sysdate);
```

The output of the select query is

```
ID      TMSTMP
--  -------------------
15  2019-02-15 20:29:31
10  2019-02-15 20:25:51
11  2019-02-15 20:26:00
12  2019-02-15 20:26:08
13  2019-02-15 20:26:16
10  2019-02-15 20:26:22
```

Now I am trying to perform below query

```
select id, max(TMSTMP) from temp_test
where TMSTMP <  TO_DATE('2019-02-15 20:28:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
group by id;
```

Result Obtained is like - Actual result

```
ID      TMSTMP
--  -------------------
13  2019-02-15 20:26:16
11  2019-02-15 20:26:00
12  2019-02-15 20:26:08
10  2019-02-15 20:26:22
```

But I was looking to obtained output like below as this is the max time after the specified time

```
ID      TMSTMP
--  -------------------
10  2019-02-15 20:26:22
```

Any other solution is really appreciated, Thank you

Small Edit to John's Answer,

what can be done if I have another column say the name and I want to apply a filter on it example;

```
select *
from temp_test
where name ='TOM' and tmstmp = (select max(tmstmp) 
            from temp_test 
            where name ='TOM' and tmstmp < TO_DATE('2019-02-15 20:28:00', 
'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'))
```

Is removing of duplicate comparision possible here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want the whole row with the max timestamp before the max date:

```
with CTE as
(
select id, tmstmp, row_number() over (order by tmstmp desc) as rn
from temp_test
where tmstmp < TO_DATE('2019-02-15 20:28:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
)
select *
from CTE
where rn = 1
```

or

```
select *
from temp_test
where tmstmp = (select max(tmstmp) 
                from temp_test 
                where tmstmp < TO_DATE('2019-02-15 20:28:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'))
```

If you group by id, the max(tmstmp) will be the max for each given id (grouping)

Comment: Hello John, thank you for the answer, can you suggest me 1 more thing if you don't mind if we have to say 1 more column say the name and I want to filter data among name say name = "Tom"  do I need to perform filter multiple times, inside subquery and query outside? because there may be chances if the timestamp is the same ?

Comment: Something like select *
from temp_test
where name ='Tom' and tmstmp = (select max(tmstmp) 
                from temp_test 
                where name ='Tom' and  tmstmp < TO_DATE('2019-02-15 20:28:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'))

Comment: @HargunSuri if you use the second method, it will need to go in both places. If using the first, it only needs to go inside the CTE

Comment: Thank you for the information John, I appreciate your effort Thanks !!